# Как заменить прозрачный фон КАРТИНКИ на белый средствами PHP?

Tags: php

Как заменить прозрачный фон КАРТИНКИ на белый средствами PHP?

Comment: а что пробовали вы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте создать изображение с белым цветом. Для этого можно использовать функцию: [imagecreate](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecreate.php)
Затем с помощью imagecopy наложите свое изображение на созданное изображение